# Flask-SQLAlchemy ArgumentError: Object is not legal as a SQL literal value

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When trying to execute a select query via SQL-Alchemy, I am presented with the following error:

`ArgumentError: Object <hello.models.User object at 0x106763210> is not legal as a SQL literal value`

models.py

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

@login_manager.user_loader
def get_user(uid):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=uid).first()
    return user
#Where code error ocurrs

class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    company = db.Column(db.String(120))
    password = db.Column(db.String(90))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

Comment: To clarify, whenever I run 'User.query.filter_by(id=uid).first()' this error is yielded or any User.query.

Answer (score 4):

In my case i executed a query which has an object instead a specific value.
This is how i got the error.

```
user=Users.query.filter_by(id=someid).first()#this was not a problem,
```

but the second query was like

```
friends=Friends.query.filter_by(user).first()#this is where i got ht problem
```

saying
flask-sqlalchemy-argumenterror-object-is-not-legal-as-a-sql-literal-value.

This means,that

> i am trying to execute a query which has an object users, instead user.id(or something like that which should be a value)

So when i realize this i changed my query to

```
Friends=Friends.query.filter_by(user.id).first()#worked fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to find some information about your problem: [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html#specific-checks-added-for-passing-mapped-classes-instances-as-sql-literals)

> The typing system now has specific checks for passing of SQLAlchemy
>   “inspectable” objects in contexts where they would otherwise be
>   handled as literal values.

I had the same problem here:

```
def increase_relation(cls, previous, current):
    current = DBSession.query(cls).filter_by(left_sound_id=previous, right_sound_id=current).first()
    rate = int((100 - current.weight) - (100 - current.weight) / 1.618)
    DBSession.query(cls).\
        filter(cls.left_sound_id==previous).\
        filter(cls.right_sound_id==current).\ # error is here
        update({"weight": cls.weight + rate})
```

As you can see, I get "current" as a parameter and overwrite it on the next line, which is wrong. 
And I fixed it this way:

```
def increase_relation(cls, previous_id, current_id):
    current_rel = DBSession.query(cls).filter_by(left_sound_id=previous_id, right_sound_id=current_id).first()
    rate = int((100 - current_rel.weight) - (100 - current_rel.weight) / 1.618)
    DBSession.query(cls).\
        filter(cls.left_sound_id==previous_id).\
        filter(cls.right_sound_id==current_id).\
        update({"weight": cls.weight + rate})
```

Check your "uid", does it have the correct type?